# how to open a python interpreter using kivyFramework

Tags: python, android, kivy

can any one say how to open python interpreter using kivyframework. I am developing an android application using python on kivyframework as side i need to open a python interpreter could any one help me regarding this

i dint see anything regarding calling an python interpreter using kivyframework could any one help me on this

Comment: You want to start a console to type python commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pyonic-interpreter](https://github.com/inclement/Pyonic-interpreter)
Also found on the authors [webpage](http://inclem.net/pages/pyonic-interpreter/)